# Anonymous function in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Let's say have file like this

```
(function () {
    function change() {
        print('test');
    }
    function test() {
        return 'Testing';
    }
})();
```

How to pass argument to this function using nashorn? I don't want run it via terminal, I have to create method that takes String as argument and process it with js code.

Comment: is not possible, I have tried.

Comment: is there something special about nashorn that prevents you from just passing the params in the last parenthesis? after quickly googling i cannot find anything that would prevent it.

Comment: forget it, i understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script above defines an anonymous function and calls it immediately! If you 'eval' that you'll get the result of that function. If you want to define an anonymous function and call it from java code, you can write something like this:

```
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

      // define an anoymous function
      JSObject multiply = (JSObject) e.eval("function(x, y) { return x*y; }");
      // call that anon function
      System.out.println(multiply.call(null, 34, 5));

      // define another anon function
      JSObject greet = (JSObject) e.eval("function(n) { print('Hello ' + n)}");
      greet.call(null, "nashorn");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around this as following:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");

String task = "function(a, b) { return a + b; }";

engine.eval("var task = " + task);

Double result = (Double) ((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("task", 10, 4);

System.out.println(result); // Output: 14.0
```